# Filter out descriptions that aren't in the component list

Tags: python, list, filter

I have 2 lists, one has lots of components and the other has the components and their description. I need to find a way to filter out all of the useless information whilst keeping the order of the description list the same as the component list.

I have tried to use list comprehension however this didn't give me the expected result.

```py
lst = [] 
for i in range (len(components)):
   lst.append([x for x in description if components[i] in x])
```

Here is a short version of the 2 variables;

```py
components = ['INVALID' , 'R100' , 'R101' , 'C100' , 'R100' , 'R100']
description = [
'  30_F "30_F";',
'  POWER_IN1 Supply   2 At     5 Volts, 0.8 Amps;',
'  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";',
'  R101          100     5     5 f PN"66151002538" "CH-WID_ 100R -5-RR 0603 (B)";',
'  C100          100n    10    10 f PN"10210616" "CFCAP X7R S 100nF 50V (T)";',
'  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";',
'  R100       CLOSED PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1 (T)"      VERSION 12046547;']
```

The output I expect is;

```py
'  INVALID    No description'
'  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";'
'  R101       100     5     5 f PN"66151002538" "CH-WID_ 100R -5-RR 0603 (B)";'
'  C100       100n    10    10 f PN"10210616" "CFCAP X7R S 100nF 50V (T)";'
'  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";'
'  R100       CLOSED PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1 (T)"      VERSION 12046547;
```

Comment: It would help to add the actual result

Comment: How would you determine that the last `R100` entry should print the description of `R100 CLOSED` and the others of `R100 OPEN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `str.startswith` function, auxiliary *seen positions* sequence and Python's `for/else` feature:

```
import pprint

...  # your input data variables

seen_pos = []
res = []
for comp in components:
    for i, desc in enumerate(description):
        if i not in seen_pos and desc.strip().startswith(comp):
            seen_pos.append(i)
            res.append('{:<10}{}'.format(comp, desc.strip().replace(comp, '', 1).strip()))
            break
    else:
        res.append('{:<10}{}'.format(comp, 'No description'))

pprint.pprint(res, width=100)
```

The output:

```
['INVALID   No description',
 'R100      OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";',
 'R101      100     5     5 f PN"66151002538" "CH-WID_ 100R -5-RR 0603 (B)";',
 'C100      100n    10    10 f PN"10210616" "CFCAP X7R S 100nF 50V (T)";',
 'R100      OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";',
 'R100      CLOSED PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1 (T)"      VERSION 12046547;']
```

Comment: This works with the small sample I provided however it doesn't work when I try to incorporate it into my code. The output is the exact same as the description list. Could this be due to a component not having a description? If so how would this be fixed?

Comment: @mark7378, start with fixing/elaborating your question to cover actual conditions so people not dive into guessing. Add the actual sample and expected result

Comment: Sorry, the actual data is much larger this is why I shortened it. I've added an additional component 'INVALID'  and updated the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
[x for x in description if x.split()[0] in components]
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution using `re`. It will maintain order that's defined in `components` list:

```
components = ['R100' , 'R101' , 'C100' , 'R100' , 'R100']
description = [
'  30_F "30_F";',
'  POWER_IN1 Supply   2 At     5 Volts, 0.8 Amps;',
'  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";',
'  R101          100     5     5 f PN"66151002538" "CH-WID_ 100R -5-RR 0603 (B)";',
'  C100          100n    10    10 f PN"10210616" "CFCAP X7R S 100nF 50V (T)";',
'  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";',
'  R100       CLOSED PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1 (T)"      VERSION 12046547;']

import re

c = iter(components)

filtered = []
current = next(c)
for line in description:
    if current and re.findall(r'^\s*{}\s*'.format(re.escape(current)), line):
        filtered.append(line)
        current = next(c, None)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(filtered, width=150)
```

Prints:

```
['  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";',
 '  R101          100     5     5 f PN"66151002538" "CH-WID_ 100R -5-RR 0603 (B)";',
 '  C100          100n    10    10 f PN"10210616" "CFCAP X7R S 100nF 50V (T)";',
 '  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";',
 '  R100       CLOSED PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1 (T)"      VERSION 12046547;']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple list comprehension with basic filtering

```
>>> res = [d for d in description if d.strip().split(' ', 1)[0] in components]
>>> pprint(res)
['  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";',
 '  R101          100     5     5 f PN"66151002538" "CH-WID_ 100R -5-RR 0603 (B)";',
 '  C100          100n    10    10 f PN"10210616" "CFCAP X7R S 100nF 50V (T)";',
 '  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";',
 '  R100       CLOSED PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1 (T)"      VERSION 12046547;']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update** OP changed the question. Checking for `'INVALID'` adds an additional layer of complexity that this answer doesn't cover.

---

Loop over the strings in `description`, and add them to the list if any of the `components` are in it.

```
comp_set = set(components)
filtered = [d for d in description if any(c in d for c in comp_set)]

for x in filtered:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";
  R101          100     5     5 f PN"66151002538" "CH-WID_ 100R -5-RR 0603 (B)";
  C100          100n    10    10 f PN"10210616" "CFCAP X7R S 100nF 50V (T)";
  R100       OPEN PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1(T)";
  R100       CLOSED PN"10057609" "RES S 5mOhm 1% 2512_H6_1 (T)"      VERSION 12046547;
```